# Error while pushing code to GIT after rebase

Tags: git, git-push

I am facing error while pushing code to GIT after rebase. I am using force push, but it also fails.
I have done rebase of my_branch from development.

I have tried

```
git push --force origin my_branch
```

it gives error as well..

```
DENIED by fallthru : (hook declined)
Enumerating objects: 52, done.
Counting objects: 100% (52/52), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32/32), 5.58 KiB | 1.39 MiB/s, done.
Total 32 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: FATAL: + refs/heads/my_branch fmea/dev_fmea_maven_webapp kumard2 DENIED by fallthru
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/my_branch 
To ssh://codex.cro.st.com/fmea/dev_fmea_maven_webapp.git
! [remote rejected] my_branch  -> my_branch  (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gitolite@codex.cro.st.com/fmea/dev_fmea_maven_webapp.git'
```

I was expecting that using force push , it should work.

Comment: "hook declined" says that the repository has a hook that has denied your push. Git would be fine with it, but someone wrote custom code that forbids it. Talk to your repo owner.

Answer (score 0):

"`DENIED by fallthru`" points to a remote repository managed by [**gitolite**](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html).

You can request an [admin for tracing the gitolite access control decision](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf-2.html#tracing-the-access-control-decision)

```
gitolite access -s dev_fmea_maven_webapp fmea W+ any
```

That will give you an idea of the rules in place.